# Bison & rec2c: Get Current line number

Tags: c++, bison, yacc

I'm dealing with PHP grammar and I want to pass to my function the line number
I have something like:
internal_functions_in_yacc:

```
        T_ISSET '(' isset_variables ')'
    |   T_EMPTY '(' variable ')'
    |   T_INCLUDE expr  { observers.IncludeFound($2); } 
    |   T_INCLUDE_ONCE expr { observers.IncludeFound($2); } 
    |   T_EVAL '(' expr ')' 
    |   T_REQUIRE expr  { observers.IncludeFound($2); } 
    |   T_REQUIRE_ONCE expr { observers.IncludeFound($2); } 
;
```

Now I want to pass line number, something like

```
T_REQUIRE_ONCE expr { observers.IncludeFound($2,$line_number_here); }
```

Is there a way to know line number of the token that bison is parsing? Or is it something that have to be done in lexing?

**EDIT**

I found lexing is done using rec2c not lex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [line numbers are enabled](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Decl-Summary) then they can be accessed using [`@n`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Locations) with n being the tokens location.

```
T_REQUIRE_ONCE expr { observers.IncludeFound($2,@2.first_line); }
```

**Edit:**

To expand on the answer `%locations` is the directive in the link that enables line numbers in bison. The lexer is still responsible for incrementing the line numbers and requires `%option yylineno`.

Lex File:

```
\n       { yylloc->lines(yyleng); yylloc->step(); }
```

Comment: I have checked lexer and it is written in rec2c not lex. I have to edit the tags. Any Idea on rec2c?

Comment: No I am sorry but if it uses bison just check the documentation for how to handle locations. It may even do it for you (I wouldn't know since I've never used it)

Comment: Since this have revealed the real solution (though not in rec2c) I will accept and just find similar thing in rec2c. 
Thanks